# How to compare the weight matrices from different gradient descent runs?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I would like to compare the end results of gradient descent for runs which use different initial weights and different orders of training data. I know that index by index in the matrix will make no sense but perhaps looking at something like the eigen values and vectors could be useful.

In a 3-layer network it would make sense that assuming they yield high accuracy (99.5) and I feed them test data in the same order, the 2 sets of weights must be doing similar things to the input vector with respect to eachother. How can I show this ?

Comment: I don't think this is an off-topic nor unclear question: OP clearly asks for a way to compare the resulting weight matrices in a meaningful way. However, I am afraid that it is not possible to do that.

Comment: Hi Jan. Ill detail what I have done so far. I run the 3 layer network on MNIST 10,000 times and collect the weights. Then I flatten these weights into vectors and make a matrix. Then I perform PCA on this matrix and extract 2500 components preserving 95% of the variance. I think one of the problems is that using random weights this matrix is completely arbitrary because of the fully connected layers. Meaning a hidden unit connected strongly to some pixels in one example could be connected very weakly in another example so the weights associated mean different things.

Comment: Perhaps could you be a bit more clear about the reason why you need this? What is it that you want to compare about the resulting matrices?

Comment: I am trying to find an explanation for direct feedback alignment. https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01596. We believe that the space of all weight matrices from direct feedback alignment should be a sub-space of back propagation.